# SQL query update delete in two tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: person and personlicense. Person is a 1:many with PersonLicense, but I have some that are 1:1 and I need to combine them.

Person has a PersonID and a ContactNumber, PersonLicense has a LicenseID with a FK of PersonID in common.

I query the two joined tables on the ContactNumber and get ContactNumber PersonID LicenseID and ExpireDate with:

```
SELECT p.ContactNumber, pl.LicenseID, p.PersonID, pl.ExpireDate
FROM Person as p INNER JOIN PersonLicense as pl
ON p.PersonID=pl.PersonID
WHERE p.ContactNumber ='130012134'
ORDER BY ExpireDate DESC
```

and the result is:

```
ContactNumber LicenseID PersonID ExpireDate
130012134 21120695 11126209 2017-05-31
130012134 21120058 11115697 NULL
```

I need to change the 2nd lines' PersonID to the PersonID in the first line, then delete the record associated with the 2nd line PersonID. I currently use:

```
UPDATE PersonLicense
SET PersonID='11126209' 
WHERE LicenseID='21120058'
```

and then:

```
ALTER TABLE PersonLicense NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_License_Person

DELETE FROM Person
WHERE PersonID='11115697'

ALTER TABLE PersonLicense CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_License_Person
```

This works fine, but I have over 2,500 to do... How can I put the above steps using ContactNumber in ('n1', 'n2', ....) into a stored procedure or script to do them all?

Comment: How do you know what personID to use when you have multiple for a given contactNumber.  Say you had 3 records in your result instead of two and each had a different personID...  You could use an analytical function such as row_number() over (Partition by contactNumber, order by expireDate) and then you update row 1, and then delete all teh non-row 1's

Comment: xQbert - I use the latest (top row of the two), hence the ORDER BY ExpireDate DESC.  There are only 2 rows now ever.  All the ones with 4 and 3 rows in result I did by hand (the above method).  Only 2 rows and update now the bottom row with the top row's PersonID and delete the bottom row's PersonID record.

Comment: xQbert - I tried the function and get all the applicable ContactNumbers shown in Row 1 and Row 2 (a total of 2500 each) sequentially.  It's still not clear to me how to nest that into the UPDATE statement.  Further, the ORDER BY ExpireDate within each quits working (sometimes the newest is in Row 2 vs. Row 1). SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY ContactNumber ORDER BY pl.ExpireDate) as ROW, ContactNumber, pl.LicenseID, p.PersonID, pl.LicenseNumber, pl.ExpireDate
FROM [IPELS_Licensing].[dbo].[Person] as p INNER JOIN [IPELS_Licensing].[dbo].[PersonLicense] as pl on p.PersonID = pl.PersonID

Comment: I would get all the null expired (lets call this group 1). then get all the non latest expiredate (call this group 2). Join them to the max expire date . so you get the update setup. next is to delete all person that is in group 1 and group 2.

Comment: Now the results look like: Row ContactNumber LicenseID PersonID ExpireDate
1 130012134 21120695 11126209 2017-05-31
2 130012134 21120058 11115697 NULL                        etc.

Comment: BobNoobGuy - that would be fine, if the UPDATE PersonLicense SET PersonID in Row 2 = PersonID in Row 1 was done And then delete the Row 2 (assuming all the Row 1 and Row 2 are in ExpireDate DESC order)